# get ordered product amount since a specific date

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, quantity

currently I have got a function that is delivering me the sold amount of any given product id, but I would like to add another filter to it. It should just take all products that have been sold today

Here my code so far:

```
public function getOrderAmount($productId) {
    $product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->getFirstItem();
    return (int)$product->ordered_qty;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [that article](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-bestselling-products-by-category-and-date-time/) about filtering products for a time range and so I could find that solution:

```
$today = time();
$last = $today + (60*60*24*7);

$from = date("Y-m-d", $today);
$to = date("Y-m-d", $last);

$product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty($from, $to)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->getFirstItem();
return (int)$product->ordered_qty;
```